# Choosing non repetitive values in dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1], index=dates, columns=list('A'))
```

Expected output from df

```
df_out=pd.DataFrame([1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,-1,1], index=dates, columns=list('A'))
```

I want to choose alternate +1 and -1 and substitute zero when there is repetition.

df can be a big dataframe of 10 columns and I want this conversion on all the columns. What is the effective way without using for loop?
Please suggest the way forward. Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: So will the values always alternate between 1 and -1? (haivng removed repetitions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you could use [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) along with [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) to check which first differences are not `0`, or in other words, which subsequent values are not repeated, and replace those that are `False` with `0` using [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df.where(df.A.diff().ne(0), 0)

            A
2013-01-01  1
2013-01-02  0
2013-01-03  0
2013-01-04 -1
2013-01-05  0
2013-01-06  0
2013-01-07  1
2013-01-08  0
2013-01-09 -1
2013-01-10  1
```

Comment: Slightly modified code of anky works too (df_out3=np.where(df.ne(df.shift()),0,df)
but I chose yours.

Comment: I thought I had accepted it. Slow internet made me look like uncivilized! Can't thank enough for everyone's time.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.2/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df.A=np.where(df.A.ne(df.A.shift()),df.A,0)
print(df)

            A
2013-01-01  1
2013-01-02  0
2013-01-03  0
2013-01-04 -1
2013-01-05  0
2013-01-06  0
2013-01-07  1
2013-01-08  0
2013-01-09 -1
2013-01-10  1
```

Comment: hmm yes but he wants alternate -1 and 1s

Comment: @yatu okay, checking that, though i feel if op has duplicate values like example, this should also work

Comment: Yeah, not sure tbh. posted someth similarr

Comment: It is giving 0,1,1,0,-1,-1,0,1,0,0

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni check again if you had used the earlier sol. I have updated now, should work

Comment: Got an idea from your code (df_out=np.where(df.ne(df.shift()),0,df)
)

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni sure, please consider to upvote if you like it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df['A'] = df['A'] * (df['A'].diff() != 0)
```

How this works:

`diff()` calculates the difference between successive values in your series. If the diff is 0 then we know there was a repetition.

Therefore we can do a `!= 0` check which will create a boolean series which will be True wherever there was no repetition and false where there was a repetition.

Boolean series can be used as a series of zeroes and ones and multiplied against the original series resulting in zeroing out all the repetitions.

Comment: Added explanation!

Answer (score 0):

A third option:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def check_dup(data):
    print(data)
    if data[0] == data[1]:
        return 0
    else:
        return data[1]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2, (10,1))*2-1)

df.rolling(window=2).apply(check_dup, raw=True)
```